# Tensorflow batch sparse multiply

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I would like to multiply a sparse tensor by a dense tensor but do so within a batch.

For example I have a sparse tensor with the corresponding dense shape of (20,65536,65536) where 20 is the batch size. I would like to multiply each (65536,65536) in the batch with the corresponding (65536x1) from a tensor shape (20,65536) which has a dense representation. `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` only accepts a rank 2 sparse tensor. Is there a way to perform this over a batch?

I would like to avoid converting the sparse matrix to a dense matrix if possible due to memory constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `a` is a sparse tensor with shape `(20, 65536, 65536)` and `b` a dense tensor with shape `(20, 65536)`, you could perform the batch sparse-dense matrix multiplication as follows:

```
y_sparse = tf.sparse.reduce_sum_sparse(a * b[:, None, :], axis=-1)
```

This solution expands the second dimension of tensor `b` to enable implicit broadcasting. Then, the batch matrix multiplication takes place by performing a sparse-dense multiplication and a sparse sum along the last axis.

If `b` has got a third dimension so it is a batch of matrices, you can multiply their columns individually and concatenate them later:

```py
multiplied_dims = []
for i in range (b.shape[-1]):
  multiplied_dims.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.sparse.reduce_sum(a * b[:, :, i][:, None, :], axis=-1), -1))
result = tf.concat(multiplied_dims, -1)
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood the the question as `b` would be of shape `(20, 65536, 1)`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just mistyped the shape of `b` in the answer (I have updated it now) - the code should work as expected

Comment: when i run this code, i get `y_sparse = tf.sparse.reduce_sum(a * b[:, None, :], axis=-1)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. I use tf 2.0 so there ist no reduce_sum_sparse. Edit: My mistake forgot to convert array to tf.Variable when testing.

Comment: Could you explain how I can expand this if I have b of shape (20,65536,3)?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to have `b` of shape `(20,65536,3)`, as broadcasting is only supported from dense to sparse, unfortunately. You could, however, perform the three matrix multiplications independently and then concatenate the results along the last axis.

Comment: okay. so it is mathematically possible but not using tensorflow only. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Well, you can still use TF for all the operations (e.g. multiplication and concatenation)

Comment: VERY HELPFUL OF YOUR ANSWER, GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - you reshape the sparse tensor first and then multiply it by the dense matrix. Something like this would work:

```
sparse_tensor_rank2 = tf.sparse_reshape(sparse_tensor, [-1, 65536])
```

Comment: could you please clarify why this would be working and expand the code untlil after the multiplication?

Comment: It will work because it's just multiplication after reshaping, but it might not satisfy every use-case I guess.