# How to get batch_size in call() function in TF2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, batchsize

I'm trying to get `batch_size` in `call()` function in TF2 model.
However, I cannot get it because all the methods I know returns `None` or Tensor instead of dimension tuple.

Here is a short example

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    
    def call(self, x):
        print(len(x))
        print(x.shape)
        print(tf.size(x))
        print(np.shape(x))
        print(x.get_shape())
        print(x.get_shape().as_list())
        print(tf.rank(x))
        print(tf.shape(x))
        print(tf.shape(x)[0])
        print(tf.shape(x)[1])        
        return tf.random.uniform((2, 10))


m = MyModel()
m.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
m.fit(np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]), np.array([0, 1]), epochs=1)
```

The output is:

```py
Tensor("my_model_26/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
(None, 4)
Tensor("my_model_26/Size:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
(None, 4)
(None, 4)
[None, 4]
Tensor("my_model_26/Rank:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("my_model_26/Shape_2:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("my_model_26/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("my_model_26/strided_slice_2:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 3.1796 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

I fed `(2,4)` numpy array as input and `(2, )` as target to the model in this example.
But as you can see, I cannot get `batch_size` in `call()` function.

The reason I need it is because I have to iterate tensors for `batch_size` which is dynamic in my real model.

For example, if the dataset size is 10 and batch size is 3, then the last batch size in last batch would be 1. So, I have to know batch size dynamically.

Can anyone help me?

---

- Tensorflow 2.3.3
- CUDA 10.2
- python 3.6.9

Comment: In `call()` method you just need to create your model. Iteration over data, should be happened in `train_step` function. Are you sure you need `batch_szie` in `call()`?

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, I need to do 3d sparse tensor batch multiplication like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075394/13132411). To do this, I have to know batch size in `call()` function as far as I know (actually I'm a pytorch user, so it could be wrong. please let me know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using TensorFlow (that's mandatory since Keras is now inside TensorFlow), and by using TensorFlow you need to be aware of the "compilation" of the dynamic graph into a static-graph.

In short, your `call` method is (under the hood) decorated with the `@tf.function` decorator.

This decorator:

1. Traces the python function execution
2. Converts the python operation in TensorFlow operations (e.g. `if a > b` becomes `tf.cond(tf.greater(a,b), something, something_else)`)
3. Creates a `tf.Graph` (the static graph)
4. Executes the static graph just created.

Al your `print` calls are executed during the first step (the python execution tracing), that's why even if you train your model you see the output only 1 time.

That said, to get the runtime (dynamic shape) of a tensor, you must use `tf.shape(x)`, the batch size is just `batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]`

Please note that if you want to see the shape (using print) you can't use print, but you must use `tf.print`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):

        shape = tf.shape(x)
        batch_size = shape[0]

        tf.print(shape, batch_size)

        return tf.random.uniform((2, 10))


m = MyModel()
m.compile(
    optimizer="Adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
m.fit(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]), np.array([0, 1]), epochs=1)
```

More information about static and dynamic shapes: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/

More info about the tf.function behavior: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/

Note: I wrote these articles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exactly the data and shapes, you may turn eager run true, but it is not a good solution, since it makes training slow.

Set it like this:

```
m.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                           metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)
```

Then the output will be:

```
(2, 4)
tf.Tensor(8, shape=(), dtype=int32)
(2, 4)
(2, 4)
[2, 4]
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 4], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By the way, I passed batch_size (int) into `call()` function and I found out that batch_size (int) is changed to 'Constant' tensor. I'm wondering why this happens. Do you have any clue about it?